# asp.net facebook login integration which works for only pre-registered users?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, authentication

I have to ask you fellow experts in here, since i have found zero material on this on the vast internet...

I want to make a facebook integration into my website, where the already registered users can use facebook to login, instead of the default username and password handed to them when i first registered them..

Basically.. i just need to check if the email they login to facebook with, exists in my database.. if it does.. the login is a success..

Hope someone has some wizardly insight into this :)

PS! And sorry for not posting any code samples, or if someone thinks this question is too trivial.. Might be i'm a lousy google'r :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the **standard MVC web application template** that includes Microsoft.AspNet.Identity adding external sign on for your users is relatively easy.

First register with Facebook so that you can allow users of your application to use Facebook authentication.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/register

Then

In your App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs file you will see the code below in the commented out state.

```
 //app.UseFacebookAuthentication(
        //   appId: "",
        //   appSecret: "");
```

Uncomment the code, and add your keys from Facebook.

Then existing users can navigate to following page to add a Facebook login to their account.

http://[YourURL]/Manage/ManageLogins

Comment: Thanks Lichen :) I'm not using MVC though.. It's WebAPI and unfortunately Web Forms... Same approach ?